# Using for loops vs using .copy() or [:] to copy a list

Tags: python, list, copy

I have a program that uses nested 2-dimensional lists (a 'grid') to display a table of values. I've got a function that replaces each cell in the grid with the sum of its neighbours, so I make a copy of the grid and replace the numbers in the copy.

```py
def sum_of_neighbors(grid):
    sum_grid = grid[:]
    # sum_grid = grid.copy()

    # sum_grid = []
    # for row in grid:
    #     row_list = []
    #     for number in row:
    #         row_list.append(number)
    #     sum_grid.append(row_list)

    for i in range(len(sum_grid)):
        for j in range(len(sum_grid[0])):
            sum_grid[i][j] = sum(find_neighbors(i, j, grid))
    return sum_grid
```

find_neighbours returns a list of the cell's neighbours in the grid.

When I take a slice of the original grid or use `.copy()`, replacing `sum_grid[i][j]` replaces the element in the original grid too, causing the find_neighbours to return the wrong values next time it runs the loop. So using `grid = [[64, 81, 21], [26, 52, 68], [84, 43, 97]]` returns `sum_grid = [[159, 326, 446], [664, 1887, 2799], [2594, 8041, 12727]]` instead of `sum_grid = [[159, 231, 201], [324, 484, 294], [121, 327, 163]]`. However, this doesnt happen when I make the copy using the for loop.

I'm not sure why this isn't working, because when I tried using '[:]'/`.copy()` in this test program, the copy changed but the original didn't.

```py
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
list1_copy = list1[:]
list1_copy[0] = list1[1]
print(list1, list1_copy)

#######################
#Output:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why does `.copy()` and `[:]` work in the test program, but not in my code, while the for loop works for both?

Comment: What's the type of `grid`? Is it a Numpy array by any chance?

Comment: Just a regular list of lists, I haven't learnt about numpy yet

Comment: Seems you need [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Oh, right! Or alternatively `[row.copy() for row in grid]`. While `grid.copy()` does copy the outer lists, the individual elements of the list are still just references to the rows of the original grid.

Comment: Sven, what do you mean by 'the individual elements of the list are still just references to the rows of the original grid'? Doesn't copy make a copy of the entire list as is?

Comment: Matthias, I saw that on another page and it worked when I tried it. I just wanted to know why the copy doesn't work when deepcopy or the for loop does

Comment: The elements of a list are just references. If you copy a list, you get a new list, but the new list still contains references to the same elements as the original list. This doesn't matter when then elements of the list are immutable, like integer numbers or strings. But if the elements of the list are lists again, this makes a difference.

Comment: @KailashSeshadri The references to the inner lists are copied too, so they are still the same in the original and the copy. The beforementioned `deepcopy` handles that.

Comment: Ah, so copy just makes a at a 'base' level but doesn't copy over every single element of each row. When I change the first element, of the grid, it doesn't change sum_grid directly, but changes the list that contains the first row?

Comment: @Matthias Yep, I think I've got it now, thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, you got it. It's a little bit surprising when you encouter it for the first time.